# Python- How to identify images in PDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, jpeg

How can I identify images inside a PDF without utilizing outside tools?  I'm looking for a way to build an image extractor from scratch.

Comment: This is too broad and vague. Have you tried *anything*? Have you done *any* research? Did you face *specific* issues on your attempt/s? Because this looks like asking someone to implement an *entire* package/library for you.

Comment: as I know PDF may have very complex construction and identify images can makes big problem. You would have to find some documentation for PDF structure - if it only exists. So this can be problem too broad for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to implement something from scratch (e.g. because you need a clean room implementation) and you don't want to cheat (i.e. copy from existing projects), all you have to go by are specifications.

In case of pdf that's ISO 32000-2 or - if supporting only pdf 1.x versions suffices - ISO 32000-1.

Of the latter Adobe provides a freely available copy in which merely the ISO headers have been removed, simply google for "PDF32000".

You may need additional specifications because pdf allows embedding certain other image formats. You find them referenced in the ISO norms.